# como adicionar evento de clique há um fragmento no andoid studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-activity, android-fragment, click

estrutura do meu projeto:
é um simples Navigation Drawer Activity, dentro de cada aba criei vários fragmentos para separar categorias que vão ser adicionados ícones clicáveis

esse é meu primeiro fragmento onde quero adicionar vario botões com eventos de cliques

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/cinza"
tools:context=".ui.rotas.ADCFragment">

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/nilah"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@mipmap/nilah_foreground"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="22dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="67dp" />
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

já usei o Android:onClick
(o removi para o metodo onClickListener)
(a unica diferença que tive foi que usando o onClick meu aplicativo carrega o fragmento onde o evento de clique vai ser feito, ja usando o onClickListener ao abrir o fragmento onde se encontra o icone clicavel a aplicaçao falha e fecha sem carregar o fragmento)

e esse é meu código em java para esse mesmo fragmento:

```
public class ADCFragment extends Fragment {

// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

public ADCFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment ADCFragment.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static ADCFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    ADCFragment fragment = new ADCFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;

}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    // Inflatethe layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a_d_c, container, false);
}
```

}

quero adicionar um evento de clique ao meu image view, já tentei:

```
public void nilahClick(){
//udsando intent
setOnclickListener
//usando intent

public void abrirNilah(View v){
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NilahFragment.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

e o código mais complexos que tentei:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_adc, container, false);

    // Configurar o OnClickListener para o botão
    Button nilahButton = view.findViewById(R.id.nilahButton);
    nilahButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Criar uma instância do NilahFragment
            NilahFragment nilahFragment = new NilahFragment();

            // Iniciar a transação de fragmento para substituir o fragmento atual pelo NilahFragment
            FragmentTransaction transaction = requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, nilahFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null); // Opcional: permite voltar ao fragmento anterior
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

}

todos travam minha aplicação assim que clico no botão, exceto o onClicklistener que faz minha aplicação travar assim que abro a aba onde está meu fragmento

provavelmente esses códigos funcionem, já que não recebi nenhum alerto de erro, e o mal funcionamento deles deve ser devido á algo que não sei fazer para completar a ação, alguém  tem ideia do que eu devo fazer? e se possível me dizer em detalhes? já que não entendo bem do assunto